# MySQL UPDATE with SELECT statement - convert to JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, select, subquery, multiple-columns

Problem: MySQL - Get the sum of IBB for each PersonID in Batting and update that IBB for each PersonID in Batting_Career

Could someone help me figure out the JOIN?

What I have that is not working:

```
UPDATE Batting_Career
SET Batting_Career.IBB = Batting.IBB WHERE PersonID IN 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT
        PersonID,
        SUM(IBB) AS IBB
    FROM
        Batting 
     GROUP BY PersonID )
AND Batting_Career.PersonID = Batting.PersonID;
```

The Batting select statement works (...) - it gets me the sum of IBB in a column IBB for all playerIDs but when I add to the update using it does not work.

The error that I am getting is

**Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

I believe the rules are **You can only select one column from such a query**. Which mean I may have to Join the tables. Could anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate in `Batting` and join to `Batting_Career`:

```
UPDATE Batting_Career bc
JOIN (
  SELECT PersonID, SUM(IBB) as IBB  
  FROM Batting 
  GROUP BY PersonID
) b ON b.PersonID = bc.PersonID
SET bc.IBB = b.IBB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a query that will do your work :)

```
UPDATE Batting_Career t2
SET t2.IBB = t1.IBB where PersonID IN (
   SELECT
        PersonID,
        SUM(IBB) AS IBB
    FROM
        Batting
    WHERE
        PersonID IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT
            PersonID
        FROM
            Batting
    )
GROUP BY
    PersonID
) t1
WHERE
    t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID;
```

Comment: I tried this and get the following error:2 errors were found during analysis.
 This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "WHERE" at position 301)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "WHERE" at position 301). Basically it does not like the last WHERE clause: WHERE  t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID;